# Animated Panel Border In Asp.Net Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

How do I make the panel border more attractive in Asp.Net Web Application-2005. Like blinking, Changing color, appear and disappear.

Is it possible in VS-2005?.

Comment: You can use jQuery on that.

Comment: @FreddieFabregas Can you guide me by some example?. Which possible on vs-2005 only.